# Alphabetically sorted links in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I've been having some trouble getting my program to insert given names along with their weights in a linked list which has a respective link for names and weights, which are both to be sorted in ascending / alphabetical order. The weight links work fine but I can't seem to identify what I'm getting wrong in my name linker. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The problem most likely lies in the insertName() private function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:
    void insert(string name, double weight);
    void printNameAsc();
    void printWeightAsc();

private:
    struct Node
    {
        string name;
        double weight;
        Node* nextName;
        Node* nextWeight;
    };
    Node* nameHead = NULL;
    Node* weightHead = NULL;
    Node* newP = NULL;

    void insertName();
    void insertWeight();
};
void DoublyLinkedList::insert(string name, double weight)
{
    // variable declaration
    newP = new Node;
    newP->name = name;
    newP->weight = weight;
    newP->nextName = NULL;
    newP->nextWeight = NULL;

    // empty first element check
    if (nameHead == NULL && weightHead == NULL)
    {
        nameHead = newP;
        weightHead = newP;
        return;
    }

    // name and weight insertion
    insertName();
    insertWeight();

    return;
}
void DoublyLinkedList::insertName()
{
    Node* activeP = nameHead;
    Node* prevP = NULL;

    // traversing through name links
    while (true)
    {
        if (activeP == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }

        if ((activeP->name).compare(newP->name))
        {
            break;
        }

        prevP = activeP;
        activeP = activeP->nextName;
    }

    //insertion
    newP->nextName = activeP;
    if (activeP == nameHead)
    {
        nameHead = newP;
    }
    else
    {
        prevP->nextName = newP;
    }

    return;
}
void DoublyLinkedList::insertWeight()
{
    Node* activeP = weightHead;
    Node* prevP = NULL;

    // traversing through weight links
    while (true)
    {
        if (activeP == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (newP->weight < activeP->weight)
        {
            break;
        }

        prevP = activeP;
        activeP = activeP->nextWeight;
    }

    //insertion
    newP->nextWeight = activeP;
    if (activeP == weightHead)
    {
        weightHead = newP;
    }
    else
    {
        prevP->nextWeight = newP;
    }

    return;
}
void DoublyLinkedList::printNameAsc()
{
    Node* activeP = nameHead;

    while (activeP != NULL)
    {
        cout << activeP->name << " " << activeP->weight << endl;
        activeP = activeP->nextName;
    }

    return;
}
void DoublyLinkedList::printWeightAsc()
{
    Node* activeP = weightHead;

    while (activeP != NULL)
    {
        cout << activeP->name << " " << activeP->weight << endl;
        activeP = activeP->nextWeight;
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    DoublyLinkedList nameList;

    nameList.insert("Michael", 275);
    nameList.insert("Tom", 150);
    nameList.insert("Abe", 200);

    nameList.printNameAsc();
    system("pause");
    nameList.printWeightAsc();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure your problem is here:

```
    if ((activeP->name).compare(newP->name) > 0)
    {
        break;
    }
```

Looks like you're finding the insertion point with activeP. When activeP->name > newP->name, you want to stop searching.

```
if ((activeP->name).compare(newP->name))
```

Is invalid, this will evaluate true if activeP < newP (compare statement is -1) or activeP > newP (compare statement is 1), effectively only skipping people with the same names.

Remember, carried over from C, truth is defined as not falseness, which is defined as (!0)

Also, why not just pass a reference of newP to insertName() and insertWeight()? It's good practice to not leave (possibly dangling) pointers stored as member variables.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of that and also completely forgot that the compare function returns -1,0 or 1 instead of a bool.

Comment: Are the potential dangling pointers the newP used inside the insertName/Weight functions?

Comment: @michael16574 nah, it's just general good practice to not save pointers that are only temporary. If newP is somehow deleted between the initialization in insert() and the call to insertName/weight, you'll get a segfault.

Comment: Wouldn't a reference to newP also be broken if newP was somehow deleted before the calls? Or is it like a "backup" reference?

Comment: Yeah, it's a contrived example that actually won't ever happen... But still, it's just not great practice to save local pointers as member variables. Consider the fact that if newp wasn't a member var, and was instead passed by reference. The only way that newp could then be invalidated is in the insertname/weight functions.

Comment: OH! I see, not sure why I made newP a member variable in the first place, might have used newP for something else when building the program before. Thank you for the heads up, I'll keep an eye out for what you have said in the future.

Comment: @michael16574 well newP is a stack-local because it's declared in the enclosing scope of a function. I'd suggest reading up on enclosing scopes in c++ for this, short answer is no, longer answer is yes, but you'll need to change the functions to take a reference to newP as a parameter

Comment: "you'll get a segfault." Unfortunately this is not always true. You should thank your lucky stars when this causes a segfault because the alternative is much worse: A rogue pointer that still references some valid, but repurposed, memory and possibly writing to some other poor object, making them look like they're the one with the buggy code. These sorts of errors are an absolute horrorshow that can take years to track down and fix if they happen rarely enough.

Comment: @user4581301 again, the dangling pointer wouldn't exist if it was never saved to the object... catch 22.